# Once authenticated in Illumina Basespace how long is the access token valid for?

Tags: oauth-2.0, illumina

I've successfully used Illumina BaseSpace to download one off dataset, access to the dataset in the project is granted with an access token.

Ideally I'd like to avoid having to authenticate with a browser repeatedly and would like to know exactly how log that access token is valid for.

Answer (score 0):

Illumina technical support have confirmed that the token generated by the oauth-website workflow is valid indefinitely